# best way to use font colors with textField.htmlText

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

What is the best way to use more than 1 font color with `textField.htmlText`?

I already use code like:

```
textField.htmlText = "blaa blaa" + "< u >"+w+"< /u >"+"blaa blaa"
```

How can I make that to define a specific color as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FONT Tag is easier

Answer (score 3):

Use [flash.text.StyleSheet](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html)

```
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
var underline:Object = new Object();
underline.fontWeight = "bold";
underline.color = "#FF0000";
underline.display = "inline";

style.setStyle("u", underline);

textField.styleSheet = style;
textField.htmlText = "blaa blaa" + "< u >"+w+"< /u >"+"blaa blaa"
```

Comment: thanks, but there is now a weird LINEFEED after +w+  caused by stylesheet?

Comment: StyleSheets are a prettier way of doing it, you just have to remember to set your styles as inline to get rid of the linebreak after them.